# imessage app unable to attach to pid

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, imessage-extension

I am trying to add an iMessage extension to my exits project to gain a new feature on ios 10 to add stickers to iMessage.

I am doing that by adding a new target from `file -> new -> target` in the Xcode project

But when building and running that on an iPhone device, it keeps showing `unable to attach to pid` error
[image]

I have googled around, some one said that I should trust profile on my iPhone device at `General -> Device Managment` But I could not find any profile to be trusted there.

Weird thing is that If I make a new project and add an iMessage extension like this, things will work fine but this couldn't happen when adding to a generated project by Unity

I also have tried to reboot my iPhone device and my Mac. and clean derived data.

How could I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

finally I found a solution [here](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unable-to-open-imessage-app-extension.461287/)

and the trick is I show change the archs to both armv7 and arm64 to make this work

[image]